# How to get theorem environment in bookdown slidy? It seems to have been removed?

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

In bookdown v0.24, it was possible to do

````
```{theorem}
my theorem
```
````

to get a theorem environment in `bookdown::slidy_presentation2` file.

This was removed in v0.25. The new way to do environments in bookdown

```
::: {.theorem}
my theorem
:::
```

works for html documents, but not slides. Is this a bug, or is there a reason this was removed from slides? How can I make a theorem environment in slidy now.

As far as I can tell, it now seems impossible to make presentation slides in R Markdown using html (as opposed to beamer) with in-built theorem environments.

Comment: You are using a too old version of bookdown. [When in doubt, try to update packages.](https://yihui.org/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/) If the problem is still present in the latest version of bookdown, you may file an issue to https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues Thanks!

Comment: @YihuiXie Thanks but I'm using the latest version v0.31, and neither theorem environment works in slidy. I'll file an issue.